# Where should the director IP be configured in LVS load balancer under Linux

Tags: linux, load-balancing, nat

The subject is quite self explanatory, I have a load balancer running LVS ldirectord, and the follwoing configuration:

```
# ipvsadm -Ln 

IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  172.22.9.100:80 rr
  -> 172.22.1.133:80              Masq    1024   0          2
  -> 172.22.1.134:80              Masq    1024   0          1
```

I declare which the Virtual IP is, but where do I specifiy the director IP, which is needed to communicate with the real servers?

Can anyone please point me to a comprehensive and up-to-date configuration, all I can find on google is ancient kernel 2.4 configuration instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Linux decides that based on it's routing tables. For example if one of your backend machines is 172.22.1.133, your host will check it's routing tables to decide which interface it should use and if it can connect directly or via a gateway.

the command 'ip route show' should give you a clue about which interface it's going to use.

If you have multiple interfaces that could be used to connect to one IP, and you want to define it separately from the rest of the routing, you can just add a route for this specific host in which you define an interface:

`ip route add 1.2.3.4/32 dev eth3`